# Copying the cell value preserving the formatting from one cell to another in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, copy, cell

In excel, I am trying to copy text from one cell to another cell in another sheet. The source cell contains formatted text *(bold,underlined,different colors)*. But when I copy the text using VBA to the other cell, the formatting is lost.

I know it is because excel is copying only the text value. Is there a way we can read the **HTML text** *(rather than plain text)* from a cell?

I have googled this and did not get any answers. I know that if we use copy and paste methods, we can copy the formatting. 
E.g.

```
Range("F10").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I10").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

**But I want to do it without a copy and paste since my destination is a merged cell and not identically sized as my source cell. Is there an option available in excel VBA to do this?**

EDIT:
I was able to solve it with the following code.

```
Range("I11").Value = Range("I10").Value
For i = 1 To Range("I10").Characters.Count
    Range("I11").Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = Range("I10").Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold
    Range("I11").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = Range("I10").Characters(i, 1).Font.Color
    Range("I11").Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic = Range("I10").Characters(i, 1).Font.Italic
    Range("I11").Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = Range("I10").Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline
    Range("I11").Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle = Range("I10").Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle
Next i
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990946/how-can-i-copy-excel-cells-with-rich-text-formatting-but-not-the-global-cell-for/39498974#39498974

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To copy formatting:

```
Range("F10").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I10:J10").Select ' note that we select the whole merged cell
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

copying the formatting will break the merged cells, so you can use this to put the cell back together

```
Range("I10:J10").Select
Selection.Merge
```

To copy a cell value, without copying anything else (and not using copy/paste), you can address the cells directly

```
Range("I10").Value = Range("F10").Value
```

other properties (font, color, [etc](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080003719&lcid=1033&NS=EXCEL.DEV&Version=14&tl=2&CTT=5&origin=HV080003718) ) can also be copied by addressing the range object properties directly in the same way

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But your method is not capturing the font colors (cell with text having different font colors)

Comment: Thanks @sean cheshire. Adding the answer as an edit to the question.

Comment: I confirm that @Sean Cheshire solution is working fine AND is also copying font styles (bold, italic, underline, color, etc.). Here is what i personally do in my macro:
Range(commentsColumnName + sSourceRowNum).Copy
Range(commentsColumnName + sTargetRowNum).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Works like a charm, while looping takes way too much time!

Answer (score 9):

Using Excel 2010 ? Try

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me with Excel 2010. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to avoid using select

```
     With sheets("sheetname").range("I10") 
          .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                  Operation:=xlNone, _
                  SkipBlanks:=False, _
                  Transpose:=False
          .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
                  Operation:=xlNone, _
                  SkipBlanks:=False, _
                  Transpose:=False
          .font.color = sheets("sheetname").range("F10").font.color
      End With
      sheets("sheetname").range("I10:J10").merge
```

Comment: Avoding select is a better approach. But, it seems that this method also don't capture the font colors as in the source cell (cell is having text with different font colors)

Comment: I updated the answer that should include font copying.  Hope this is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CopyValueWithFormatting()
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy
    With Sheet2.Range("B1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: your answer was perfect in my case

Answer (score 0):

**Copying the Bold Text From one sheet to another sheet in excel By using VBScript**
'Create instance Object

```
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.application")
oXL.Visible = True

Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("FilePath.xlsx")
Set oSheet = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")         'Source Sheet in workbook
Set oDestSheet = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet2")       'Destination sheet in workbook

r = oSheet.usedrange.rows.Count
c = oSheet.usedrange.columns.Count

For i = 1 To r
    For j = 1 To c
        If oSheet.Cells(i,j).font.Bold = True Then

            oSheet.cells(i,j).copy
            oDestSheet.Cells(i,j).pastespecial
        End If
    Next
Next

oWB.Close
oXL.Quit
```