# How can python copy excel cells value together with its color and equation,etc

Tags: python, excel, com, win32com, openpyxl

searched and tried, have not find out the solution so far...

**1.** use **openpyxl**

e.g.: `ws_to.cell(row1, column1).value =　ws_from.cell(row2,column2).value`

**2.** use **win32com.client**

e.g.:

```
xlsSheet.Cells(row1, column1).Value = xlsSheet.Cells(row2, coloum2).Value
```

The two module above both failed to copy cells keeping its color and equation.

Is there any more robust module to help me keep the color and equation when copy cells?

Comment: `.Value` will take the value only, without any formatting. Look for other properties (or see if you can use those libraries without the `.value`) and see what that copies.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848986/copying-the-cell-value-preserving-the-formatting-from-one-cell-to-another-in-exc

Comment: Were none of the answers suitable?

Answer (score 1):

With `win32com.client` you can use `Range.Copy(destination)`:

```
xlsSheet.Cells(row2, column2).Copy(xlsSheet.Cells(row1, column1))
```

This copies everything as if you did ctrl-c ctrl-v (value, formatting etc).

Comment: Any way to do this with `openpyxl`?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. there is already an answer for how to do this with openpyxl

Comment: Indeed, it's strange I did not see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With openpyxl, you can do this like:

```
# With openpyxl 1.8:
#  Make sure you're loading with load_workbook('file.xlsx', data_only=False)
#  Note: this behavior may be changing with openpyxl 1.9 in the future

# First, copy the value
ws_to.cell(row1, column1).value =　ws_from.cell(row2,column2).value

# Second, copy the style
# Styles are stored in a table on the worksheet, you can directly copy there
# Also, set the static flag, so it knows the style is shared
# And will make a copy if you edit the style on the cell afterwards
from_style = ws_from.cell(row2,column2).style
to_coord = ws_to_cell(row1, column1).get_coordinate()
from_style.static = True  # Means the style is shared, usually only set when reading a file
ws._styles[to_coord] = from_style
```

Comment: Is it `to_coord = ws_to_cell` or `to_coord = ws_to.cell` (with a `.`)?

Answer (score -1):

Using openpyxl 2.3.5, this successfully copies one cell to another including color/equations:

```
to_cell = ws_to.cell(row1, column1)
from_cell = ws_from.cell(row2,column2)

to_cell.value = from_cell.value
to_cell.style = from_cell.style
```