# copying colour in excel table and displaying in outlook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, outlook

I am using a script that copies an excel sheet and pastes it into outlook but I am wondering if there's a way to copy the formatting and colour coding aswell?

Here is the script

```
import win32com.client as client
import pandas as pd
workbook_path = r'C:\sheet\to\excel\excel.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(workbook_path, sheet_name="Sheet1",index_col=False, nrows = 10,  usecols = "A:AA")
html_body = """
     <div>
          <p>Hi All, </p>     
          <p>writing in here </p>
     </div>
     <div>
           
     </div>
 """
body = df.to_html()
proper = html_body + body
outlook =client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'emailAddress'
mail.HTMLBody = (proper)
mail.Display()
```

Comment: Perhaps using the `openpyxl` library? I don't have too much experience with this library, but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838194/how-can-python-copy-excel-cells-value-together-with-its-color-and-equation-etc) would help?

Comment: I cant seem to find any solutions in openpyxl
a lot of the answers copy from one excel to another and I cant seem to get it to work for an email