# Modifying string in cell without getting rid of formatting (underlines)

Tags: vba, excel, replace, underline

I'm currently parsing out words in an excel file using VBA, and one of the ways I've decided to split up the words is by using their existing underlines (some are already underlined, some aren't). The line that's giving me trouble is

```
Rng.Value2 = Replace(Rng.Value2, Left(Rng.Value2, I - 1), "")
```

Where Rng is referring to one cell and I is a counter in a for loop. This line of code turns this

> **Euthyatira pudens** Dogwood Thyatirid **Habrosyne scripta** Lettered Habrosyne **Habrosyne gloriosa** Glorious Habrosyne

into this

> Habrosyne scripta Lettered Habrosyne Habrosyne gloriosa Glorious Habrosyne

Except instead of bolded words, they're underlined (this text editor can't do underlines). Any idea why this is happening and how to keep the underlines?

Edit: I can make it work in a long, roundabout way (stepping through the string one character at a time and comparing it to the original string to see if that character should be re-underlined, but this takes the computer a long time. Any faster ways that don't involve stepping though the string one character at a time?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the cell's `Characters` collection if you want to preserve existing formatting.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-characters-property-excel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848986/copying-the-cell-value-preserving-the-formatting-from-one-cell-to-another-in-exc

Comment: TIM: So I've tried changing the line to     Rng.Characters = Replace(Rng.Characters, Left(Rng.Characters, I - 1), "") without luck.  How do I use the Characters property?

Comment: MARUCCI: Thanks for the link. That was one I looked at earlier, but one thing I omitted from showing in the code here was that I've already copied with formatting. Now I need to modify the string (get rid of a bit at the front) and it's keeping the formatting during that process that's giving me trouble.